# webflux returns a list of empty objects

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm new to programming with Spring. I am testing reactive programming with the Reactor / Webflux project.

Database registration works well via a Post.

But every API call Get Mono or Flux I get a list of empty objects.
Could you please give me a solution?

I initiated the project via Spring boot / Maven in Kotlin and Mongo reactive.

Thank you for your help !

My UsersApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
class UsersMsApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<UsersMsApplication>(*args)
}
```

My model :

```
@Document(collection = "user")
data class User(
                @Id
                private var id: String,
                @Field("name")
                private var name: String
                ) : Serializable
```

My repository

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String>
```

My UserService

```
interface UserService {
    fun createUser(user: User): Mono<User>

    fun findAllUsers(): Flux<User>

    fun findOneById(id: String): Mono<User>
}
```

My UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
class UserServiceImpl(private val userRepository: UserRepository): UserService {
    override fun createUser(user: User): Mono<User> {
        return userRepository.save(user)
    }

    override fun findAllUsers(): Flux<User> {
        return userRepository.findAll()
    }

    override fun findOneById(id: String): Mono<User> {
        return userRepository.findById(id)
    }
}
```

My UserRessource

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class UserResource(private val userService: UserService) {

    @PostMapping("/users")
    fun addUser(@RequestBody user: User) : Mono<User> = userService.createUser(user)

    @GetMapping("/users")
    fun findAllUsers() : Flux<User> = userService.findAllUsers()

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    fun getOneUser(@PathVariable id: String) : Mono<User> = userService.findOneById(id)

}
```

My application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=users_db

logging.level.org.springframework.data=debug
```

I have three entries in the database but here is what I returned as results by postman, a curl or the browser :

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

and in my console :

2019-05-07 15:05:13.368 DEBUG 25022 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.s.d.m.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate       : find using query: { } fields: Document{{}} for class: class com.inovans.backend.usersms.domains.User in collection: user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `User` data class all your members are declared as private, so won't be serialized to JSON when returned to the client. Change them to public (just remove the word `private`, as it'll default to public) and hopefully that'll help.

Answer (score 1):

**As for Java**, instead of making all data publicly available, you can create setters/getters for the corresponding fields and create no args constructor.

A more declarative way is to use the **Lombok Project annotations**.

```
@Data *// This annotation includes all you need*
@Document("yourDocName")
public class YourClass {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("FieldName")
    private String myField;
}
```

Hope this is useful to someone :)